# Error when starting JBoss

Tags: jboss, server, jboss7.x

Get the below error when starting the JBoss. Tried reuploading the jars, wars and the modules. Wasn't of much help.

```
Starting jboss-as: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.initAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:87)
   at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:85)
   at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:72)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.jboss.modules.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:72)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:255)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem configuring DatatypeFactory
   at __redirected.__DatatypeFactory.<clinit>(__DatatypeFactory.java:70)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   ...7 more
Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
   at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
   at __redirected.__DatatypeFactory.<clinit>(__DatatypeFactory.java:62)
   ...8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.10)
   at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
   ...9 more
```

Comment: Configure the java path in standalone.conf. This would solve your problem.

Comment: It is defined already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the above issue by updating Java. I was using java 1.5 I updated to java 1.7.xx. I am not getting the Error any more, also my application works fine.

I am curious to know what causes this issue, If anyone could answer this it will be helpful